# What are the best practices to speed up site development with CMS?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, joomla

How can I speed up site development with a particular CMS if I need to build a lot of sites?
Should I prepare a few different solutions based on barebone CMS but with pre-built components and deploy them if similar site is being requested for production? 
Or should I use some solution generator like [Joomla-Builder](http://Joomla-Builder.Com)?
Are there any tools for collaborative development of CMS-based sites?

Answer (score 2):

Version control helps with collaboration. I use git. A good bug tracker keeps everyone in the picture.

For tasks I perform over and over (like install and upgrade) I capture these tasks in a build file and run it with Apache Ant.

Drupal has install profiles which don't have much documentation but are very helpful once you get the hang of them. This enables you to switch on various components as you see fit. I also run import scripts through them which grab content from CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Found good a description of Drupal profiles with examples:
http://drupal.org/node/67921

It should be Helpful when praparing custom Drupal builds for one's own site builder's toolbox with pre-installed components.
Don't know if there is such a thing in Joomla.